# Options for ipod nano development?

Tags: ipod, ipod-nano

My wife recently bought a nano, and I wanted to write a simple program for it.  It appears that Apple has only released an SDK for the iPhone/iPod Touch without the ability to target the nano.

What are the options to create an app targeted at the nano and install it onto hers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet would likely be to get her an iPodTouch or an iPhone and work towards [developing on those](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/). They will have support, and familiar tools. I don't think there's any supported development options for the Nano (or every will be). Consider also that the [iPad will be an easy transition](http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/) once you're familiar with iPhone development.

Comment: I was very afraid this would be the answer.  Two problems.  The nano is already purchased, and unfortunately the touch and the iPhone are a bit large for someone looking to wear it while running or biking.  Also, the program I want to write is very simple and related to interval training and would be a perfect fit for a nano.  Don't tell anyone, but I already wrote it in XNA for the zune.  Yes... I own a zune.

Comment: If you can run/bike with a Zune, why can't you run/bike with a Touch or an iPhone?

Comment: I'm talking the smaller zune (the one that is nearly identical in size to the new nanos) not the zune HD.  Granted, the zune and nano are bigger than a shuffle or something like that, but still 1/2 the size of a touch or iphone, and even at that it is bordering on too bulky for my taste.

Answer (score 1):

I’m pretty sure there are none.

Answer (score 1):

There are no official ones, but you can get Linux on the iPod Nano. Then you can do pretty much anything you want.

Reference: http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/53221

- Christian

Comment: interesting, but much further than I was hoping to go.

Comment: The link to the linux source is broken... 8-(

Answer (score 0):

I currently use my Ipod Nano as a watch and have been looking for different apps to try out, but no luck.
Seems like there are no apps for nano......