# How to develop software for an ipod Nano 5G on Windows

Tags: windows, ipod

Important:

- Nano, ie not Touch.
- 5G ie not 4G or less.
- On a windows pc, not a mac or linux.

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284896/options-for-ipod-nano-development) supported way to do it. Though you might wanna check [Rockbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockbox) and/or [Freemyipod](http://www.freemyipod.org/wiki/Main_Page) but I doubt there is much sense into doing so. Anyway - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to give you the bad new Koryphae... As far as I know you can't develop apps for the Nano. Even if you could you wouldn't be able to do it on a PC.